# Logging asynchronously in C# WCF

Tags: wcf, logging, asynchronous, async-await, enterprise-library

```
public List<Users> MyFunction(string Userid)
{
    List<Users> MyUsers = new List<Users>();
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
Log.WriteLog("My Function Method is called by " + UserId);
return MyUsers;  // List of users
}
```

Log.WriteLog(...); method returns nothing in my code to return MyUsers object and at the back perform logging for me.

I have already done this with my logging function

```
public async static void WriteLog(string UserId)
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

But it is not returning data before logging. How can i make my function return data without caring for logwrite method to complte???

Comment: Your question is not clear! You want your function WriteLog() to keep Logging without blocking MyFunction()???

Comment: What is inside `WriteLog()`? Does it contain any `await`s? If not, you should be getting a warning that explains exactly what the problem is.

Comment: ok see this 
    Task.Run(() => Log.WriteLog("My Function Method is called by " + UserId));
What i want to do, i have accomplished by this. But is there any way to do it by async???

Comment: @Yawar `async` doesn't mean “run this code on another thread”, that's exactly what `Task.Run()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, make changes to `WriteLog(string UserId)` method.

```
public async static Task WriteLog(string UserId)
{
   //Your code here
}
```

And then call it from `MyFunction()`.

```
public List<Users> MyFunction(string Userid)
{
   List<Users> MyUsers = new List<Users>();
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
   //Log.WriteLog("My Function Method is called by " + UserId);
   Task t = WriteLog("My Function Method is called by " + UserId);
   return MyUsers;  // List of users
}
```

In this way, your function `MyFunction()` will continue to work and won't rely on **Logging**. In case, you want to wait for `WriteLog()` method for completion, then add `await t;` after this statement `Task t = WriteLog("My Function Method is called by " + UserId);`

Hope this will help you. More help on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx).